# Is there a Queue/FIFO data structure for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, queue, data-structures

Before I roll my own **Queue** using `NSMutableArray`, I'd like to know if there is something more standard available.  I don't see anything in the Apple docs, but I'll be surprised if there is not a Queue implementation from somewhere that folks are using.  Java spoils me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implementing a queue based on `NSMutableArray` is pretty easy, it's probably under 50 lines of code.

EDIT:

Found this with a quick google search:

```
@interface Queue:NSObject {
   NSMutableArray* objects;
}
- (void)addObject:(id)object;
- (id)takeObject;
@end

@implementation Queue

- (id)init {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
       objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [objects release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)addObject:(id)object {
   [objects addObject:object];
}

- (id)takeObject  {
   id object = nil;
   if ([objects count] > 0) {
       object = [[[objects objectAtIndex:0] retain] autorelease];
       [objects removeObjectAtIndex:0];
   }
   return object;
}

@end
```

Comment: +1 I cleaned up the code formatting a tad, and the -takeObject method.

Comment: add a [objects release] on your dealloc an I'll give you a +1

Comment: A better implementation would be a linked list.  With a linked list you can optimize the time spent doing each operation to O(1).

With NSMutableArray you have an O(n) operation for each takeObject (removeObjectAtIndex will shift all elements down).

Comment: Missing a { to open the block for takeObject. Nice answer, though :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Cocoa itself doesn't have a Queue class, and there's not a standard per se, but there are several options, one of which may best fit your needs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817469/) (and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817469/#973747)).

Like you said, you can roll your own using NSMutableArray. If you just need a quick'n'dirty queue (and aren't worried about copying, encoding/decoding, enumeration, etc.) then the solution @Matt suggests is an easy approach. You should also consider [adding queue methods to `NSMutableArray` via a category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817469/#936497), which is nice in that your "queue" is also an array (so you can pass it for NSArray parameters), and you get all the NS(Mutable)Array functionality for free.

If performance is important, I recommend using a structure more ideally suited for removing the first element. I wrote [CHCircularBufferQueue](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/interface_c_h_circular_buffer_queue.html) for my own framework for this very reason. (Not trying to toot my own horn, just trying to save others some time.)

Answer (score 1):

I have made a category containing just the deque method, based on Matt Bridges code.

```
@interface NSMutableArray (ShiftExtension)
// returns the first element of self and removes it
-(id)shift;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (ShiftExtension)
-(id)shift {
    if([self count] < 1) return nil;
    id obj = [[[self objectAtIndex:0] retain] autorelease];
    [self removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    return obj;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the STL queue from the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: I've found objective c++ to have issues with iterators in Xcode9 (9.2).  Iterators for maps do not detect map->end() correctly in the scenario I encountered. I'd minimize c++ STL uses in pure iOS code and try to keep c++ to interface layers with C++ APIs.

Another complication of C++ code will be memory management as ARC does not deal with C++ objects.  It's not a show stopper, but something to keep in mind if you are used to ARC cleaning up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [STL priority queue](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html). It requires zero lines of code and it's portable! What more could you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the :lastObject method of NSArray.  Here is an untested example:

Queue.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Queue : NSObject

-(void)enqueue:(id)object;
-(id)dequeue;

@end
```

Queue.m

```
#import "Queue.h"

@interface Queue()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *backingArray;

@end

@implementation Queue

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.backingArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)enqueue:(id<NSObject>)object {
    [self.backingArray addObject:object];
}

-(id)dequeue {
    id object = [self.backingArray lastObject];
    [self.backingArray removeObject:object];
    return object;
}

@end
```