# Is there Queue Data Structure in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Is there Queue Data Structure in Objective-C just like C# or Java? If not, what data structure  should I use to do Enqueue and Dequeue? Thanks.

Comment: Use [NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/a/936497/1031955).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are not too many elements in the queue an `NSMutableArray` is suitable. When the overhead of shifting elements really becomes a problem, you should consider using Objective-C++ and a `std::dequeue`.