# Detect if an int repeats continuously

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, timer

In my iPhone application i am using Accelerometer to find the movement of the device.

using some formula I am finding a int value (P) with the x,y and z acceleration.
this P value is being found in every .5 seconds.

I want to show an alert if the P value is same for continuous 4 times.
How to do this.

Comment: Did you try using a counter?

Comment: You're taking the integer value of the acceleration data? You'll lose a majority of the data this way considering it's all stored as doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a queue data structure (you can find Objective-C implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817469/how-do-i-make-and-use-a-queue-in-objective-c)) with a length of 4. After enqueuing new element you should check if all elements in the queue are equal (assuming they're integers).

Answer (score 1):

I have declared one more integer Q.
and if P is a particular value - I am incrementing Q else making Q = 0.
And when Q = 4 I am doing my stuff.